# In bash what is the difference between $@ and "$@"?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am aware the $@ gives the value of all arguments passed.
Suppose if the arguments passed are `a, b, "c\ d"` and if I print them one by one like:

```
    #!bin/bash
    for i in $@
     do
     echo $i 
     done
```

then the output is:

```
a
b
c
d
```

and not

```
a
b
c d
```

why does it only work if i replace $@ with "$@"? I wish to know the rules behind this. Is "$@" considered as string?

Comment: It's all in [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html), explicitly.

Comment: Lesson -- always quote your variables...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to make it clear

shell program file

```
# case 1
for i in $@;
  do echo $i
done

# case 2
for i in "$@";
  do echo $i
done
```

When executed this is the output

```
$ bash  p1.sh a b "c d"
a
b
c
d
a
b
c d
```

What happens is that the bash shell that is invoking, the interactive shell first
splits the parameters into tokens.  Next the quotes are removed ( see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal )

What is passed to the program p1.sh is this quoteless list of tokens

In the first case what is really happening is

```
for i in a b c d;
```

in the second case

```
for i in "a" "b" "c d";
```

The third token gets to the program as c**SPACE**d.   I'm writing the literal space character (ASCII 0x20) as **SPACE**

But unless the quotes are used to interpolate it the **SPACE** is seen by the command as a separator between tokens and so c**SPACE**d becomes a pair of tokens instead of one token